# get channel name and send a message over at that channel

Tags: discord.py

So I am working on a little project here, and pretty much, I want to have one of those "Please type the name of a channel in this server" feature.

So pretty much, the bot asks for a channel name, and I put in for example "#changelog" - and then it will ask for what it should write in that channel, etc etc.
So need to get the channel id (I am guessing), but I don't want users to write the ID, instead only writing the #server-name. And then whenever I have done that, the bot shall write in that channel.

Here is my current code!

```
class Changelog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Changelog is loaded')

    @commands.command()
    async def clhook(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Write text-channel: ')
        text_channel = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
        clhook = self.client.get_channel(text_channel)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Changelog(client))
```

Edit:
The channel ID shall be saved "forever", meaning that I do not have to re-write the channel name where the message should go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `discord.utils.get()` with this example:

```py
text_channel = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name=text_channel)
await channel.send('Bla Bla')
```

So when you type `(prefix)clhook` then only the channel name, for example **general**, it will send `Bla Bla` to the channel named **general** .

There is another way to do this and I think it's simple than the first option, here it is:

```py
@commands.command()
async def clhook(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.send('Bla Bla')
```

So in this command, usage is changed. You can use that with this: `(prefix)clhook #general(mention the channel)`. I suggest this solution and I think it's more useful.

Comment: Okay so, let's see if I got this. The first there gave me some errors, `'NoneType' object has no attribute send`, this is in a cog. Does `self` has to be included somewhere? Or what does this error mean?

Comment: It means that the channel is not exist or maybe related to self. Did you tried the second solution?

Comment: Well, in the second solution there. I have not tested - how would I get the channel the user is putting in?

Comment: In the second solution, used will just type `(prefix)clhook #channel-name` then it'll send message to that channel.

Comment: Or ohh, so everytime I need to write a message to that specific channel, I need to run `!!clhook #text-channel`? I wanted it more like, you write it once, and it will always apply to that channel. So `!!clhook #text-channel` would be the "hook" command, and after that all I need to write is `!!changelog <text-goes-here>`, and it will always write there.

Comment: If you always want it to use that channel, you should create a database & store the channel-id's for every server & then for every command, check what channel you're supposed to send the messages to.

Comment: I need a database for that? Oh wow, thought it was just getting the server name, and "converting" it to an ID, and storing in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `message.channel_mentions`. This will return a `list` of all channels that were mentioned using the `#channel-name` notation. That way, you can just use `channel.id` to get the `id` of the channel they mentioned.

Don't forget, however, to check if the user *did* in fact tag a channel (which you can also put in your `check`). I put it in a separate function to make it a bit more readable for the sake of this reply, but you can fit that in your lambda if you really want to.

Also, make sure to check if it's a `Text Channel` and not a `Voice Channel` or `Category Channel`.

```
@commands.command()
async def clhook(self, ctx):

    def check(self, message):
        author_ok = message.author == ctx.author  # Sent by the same author
        mentioned_channel = len(message.channel_mentions) == 1 and isinstance(message.channel_mentions[0], discord.TextChannel)
        return author_ok and mentioned_channel

    await ctx.send("Write text-channel: ")
    text_channel = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    chlhook = text_channel.channel_mentions[0]
```

I put two conditions on the `mentioned_channel` line, because if the first one fails, the second one could cause an IndexError. Alternatively you can also use an `if-statement` to return sooner at that place to solve the same issue.

Comment: Ahhh I see, but for`chlhook`, would that be where the channel name is "stored"? Or how do I send like a "test" message to that channel?

Comment: No, it doesn't store the `name`, but you pull the actual `channel` instance out of the list, so you can just do `clhook.send()` to send messages to it, or use `clhook.id` to get it's id. This way, you don't have to use `utils.get()` to find the channel object, as you already have it. You might wanna rename it though, as it could mess things up (it has the same name as your function).